# Discord.js bot audit logs problems (v12)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am writing my first bot and I have some problems with audit logs.

I want to create audit logs, which will be sending information, who kicked a member from the server.

I found something on the internet but it is working really weirdly. When I am kicking my test account, it is okay, it shows that I kicked him. But when I want to leave on my own, the log says that I am kicking this test account. What is more, when my friend is kicking this account, it is okay ant it says that he kicked him, but when I am leaving on my own again, it says that this friend kicked him. I don't know how to repair it.

Here's my code:

```js
bot.on('guildMemberRemove', async member => {
    const kanal = bot.channels.cache.get("698649855727501402");
    const fetchedLogs = await member.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        limit: 1,
        type: 'MEMBER_KICK',
    });
    const kickLog = fetchedLogs.entries.first();
    if (!kickLog)  return kanal.send(`${member.user.tag} left the guild, most likely of their own will.`);

    const { executor, target } = kickLog;

    if (target.id === member.id) {
        kanal.send(`${member.user.tag} left the guild; kicked by ${executor.tag}?`);
    } else {
        kanal.send(`${member.user.tag} left the guild, audit log fetch was inconclusive.`);
    }
});
```

[image: Screenshot of 4 messages from a Discord bot]

Comment: It'd be better if you posted your code here and you need to clarify your question more

Comment: I don't know what do you mean with "clarify my question", you mean to add some details or make it more transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are getting is caused because you are *always* fetching audit logs, and *always* use latest entry. When you leave on your own, there is no audit log entry generated at all. Additionally, latest entry for your fetch will be the same kick every time you fetch without there being new kick.

To avoid that, you should compare time of when someone left, and when was the log you fetched generated. Note however, that audit logs don't have to be generated immediately, if ever.

Snippet below should allow you to do what you want - it checks if fetched kick log was created over 5s earlier than your fetch. That time window should be long enough to account for delays etc., but you are free to make it smaller.

```js
const logs = await member.guild.fetchAuditLogs({ limit: 1, type: 'MEMBER_KICK' });
const log = logs.entries.first();
if (!log) return;
if (Date.now() - log.createdTimestamp < 5000) {
  kanal.send(`${member.user.tag} was kicked by ${log.executor.tag}.`);
} else {
  kanal.send(`${member.user.tag} left the guild.`);
}
```

Comment: Okay, I see the problem, but still I can't solve it. How can I get this time?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am an idiot, I forget about "Date.now()", which I used 30 lines higher :D Once more, thank you!